# Datatype Mismatch criteria while comparing two dates from database

Tags: vb.net

In the below comparing two dates and fetching data.But from the form am getting two date correctly and it was showing an error datatype mismatch any one please help me how to resolve this issuse.

Form.vb:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source="
        dataFile = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Add_Student Where Fee_Date between '" + DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "' and '" + DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "'", myConnection)
        da.Fill(dt)
        Add_StudentDataGridView.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
        myConnection.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing `DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()` to `DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` and doing the same for the next one. It should provide a format that is more .. interchangeable. Hope it helps

Comment: On a side note - after you sort this out, make sure you parametrize the query - this is very SQL-injection vulnerable.

Comment: Use a parametrized query (`"Select * from Add_Student Where Fee_Date between ? and ?"` with two parameters for start and end dates).  Once you have learnt how to do this, you will be protected from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: still am getting same error Mihai Ovidiu Drăgoi

Comment: jmcilhinney'a answer seems robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Access then the proper way to format date literals is the same way it's done in VB, i.e.

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Add_Student Where Fee_Date between #" + DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt") + "# and #" + DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt") + "#", myConnection)
```

You should remove the time portion if you only want to compare the date.

Using `&` operators in expressions like that is hard to read though.  Instead, you should use `String.Format`:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("Select * from Add_Student Where Fee_Date between #{0:d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt}# and #{1:d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt}#",
                                        DateTimePicker1.Value,
                                        DateTimePicker2.Value),
                          myConnection)
```

or, in recent versions of VB, string interpolation:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter($"Select * from Add_Student Where Fee_Date between #{DateTimePicker1.Value:d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt}# and #{1:d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt}#",
                          myConnection)
```

Of course, the best option is to not use any type of string concatenation and use parameters instead:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter($"Select * from Add_Student Where Fee_Date between @StartDate and @EndDate",
                          myConnection)

With da.SelectCommand.Parameters
    .AddWithValue("@StartDate", DateTimePicker1.Value)
    .AddWithValue("@EndDate", DateTimePicker2.Value)
End With
```

[Click here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) for more information on using ADO.NET parameters.

Note: I think that Access supports "h:mm:ss tt" for time but, if not, try "HH:mm:ss".

Comment: small doubt while comparing two dates are same then nothing displaying

Comment: If your database column contains only dates and no times then you need to trim the time off your filter values. If you use one of the first three examples then simply omit the time portion of the format string. If you're using parameters then use `DateTimePicker1.Value.Date` to zero the time of the parameter value. If that doesn't fix it then you're going to have to be more specific about what the database contains and what exact code and parameter values you're using. That's probably something for a new question.

Comment: Thank again got it